# Run multiple OS commands

Tags: java, process, exec

How can I run multiple OS commands in Java?  I'm using the following code to run OS commands:

```
System.out.println("Please Insert an URL ");

String https_url = input.next();
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"C:\\OpenSSL\" && openssl s_client -connect "+https_url);
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process pr = builder.start();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while (true)
        {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;
     System.out.println(line);
}
```

After running the command above I need to run two more commands -

1. HEAD / HTTP/1.1
2. R in order to check session renegotation.

How can I run multiple commands in the same OpenSSL windows?

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried threading the app, and running each one in a thread?

Comment: Please review the [edits](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20869048/revisions) to see how make an ordered list format correctly.  There ios no need for such a large code indent.

Comment: If the goal is to read from an https URL, wouldn't it be easier to do `new URL(https_url).openStream()`?